# Unexpected token 'for' List <Case>

Tags: apex, case, service

**Good morning community!**

I hope your are doing well!

I've got two errors in my code. Can you help me?

[image]

Here is my code:

```
public with sharing Class CaseService {
    
    public static void CloseCases(Set<Id> caseIds, string closingReason) {
        if (caseIds == null || caseIds.size() == 0) {
            throw new CaseServiceException('Which case to Close?');
            }
  
        List<Case> casesToClose = [SELECT Id, Status, Reason FROM Case WHERE Id IN:caseIds];
        List<Case> closedCases = newList<Case>
    
        for(Case caseToClose : casesToClose) { 
            caseToClose.Status = 'Closed';
            caseToClose.Reason = closingReason;
            closedCases.add(caseToClose);    
        }
    
        SavePoint sp = DataBase.setSavepoint();
        if (closedCases.size() <0) {
            try {
                 update closedcases; 
            } catch (Exception e){
                Database.rollback(sp);
                throw e;
            }
        }  
    }
    
    public class CaseServiceException extends Exception{}
```

Comment: You have not included the ';' after the List<Case> closedCases = newList<Case>

Comment: @DaveHumm, oh yeah.                                                                                             List<Case> closedCases = new List <Case>();

Comment: How to put solved for the question?

Comment: You can only set to solved the next day if I recall correctly. Please also accept the answer if it resolves your issue.

Answer (score 0):

Please change `List<Case> closedCases = newList<Case>` to `List<Case> closedCases = new List<Case>();`. The changes:

- added semicolon to the end
- added space between `new` and `List<Case>`

Comment: Thank you for you anwer @Jack Veromeev